# Let $G = (V, E)$ be a connected graph. Show that $|V| \le |E| + 1$.

Tags: graph-theory

> Let $G = (V, E)$ be a connected graph. Show that $|V| \le |E| + 1$.

I tried to solve this by induction on the number of edges of $G$. For $|V| = 1$, there is nothing to show. So let's assume that $|V| = 2$. Since the graph is connected, there must be an edge between those two vertices, hence, $|E| = 1$ and thus

$$|V| = 2 \le 2 = |E| + 1.$$

Now let the statement be true for $|V| = n$. We add another vertex $v_{new}$ to the graph. We call this new graph $G_{new}$. $G_{new}$ stills needs to be a connected graph, and there are two possibilities to guarantee this:

1. There is a new edge between $v_{new}$ and some arbitrary vertex of $G$, making $G_{new}$ indeed a connected graph.
2. $v_{new}$ is placed on an edge that already exists in $G$, thus dividing this edge into two different edges. Again, $G_{new}$ is a connected graph now.

In both cases, $|V_{G_{new}}| = |V| + 1$ and $|E_{G_{new}}| = |E| + 1$, so overall, we receive

$$|V_{G_{new}}| \le |E_{G_{new}}| + 1,$$

which needed to be shown.

Are there any flaws in this proof?

Comment: Hint for the question: arbitrarily choose a vertex, and attach an edge onto it, and show that there is an injection from the set of original vertices to the set of original edges plus the new edge.

Answer (score 2):

You take a graph with $n$ vertices and then, you add a vertex. This assumes that every graph with $n+1$ vertices can be built this way. It may be true, but you don't want to make weird assumptions. In addition, you claim with no proof that $G_{new}$ is connected ("stills needs to be a connected graph"). In fact, you "show" that $|V|=|E|+1$ for every connected graph, which is neatly false.

The correct approach is taking a connected graph $G$ with $n+1$ vertices, and then delete a vertex $v$ (and the $k$ edges attached to it, of course) and call this new graph $G'$. $G'$ has $j$ connected components, and $k\ge j$, because for every component $C$ of $G'$ there is at least an edge of $G$ that joins $C$ to $v$. Can you finish?

Answer (score 0):

Proof by induction on number of nodes $|V|$. The case where $|V| \leq 2$ is trivial. For $|V| = k \geq 3$, consider any node that is either on a cycle or has degree $\text d (v) = 1$ (prove the existence of such a node first), then apply the induction step.

Comment: So my proof is not correct then?